# react-fullpage right nav toggle missing

Tags: reactjs, web

I've tried react-fullpage feature using this github source without using fullpage.js

[source](http://%20https://github.com/thierryc/react-fullpage)

As per the code and demo, there should be a dotted navbar on right, in which the dot referring to current screen which will be highlighted and on click on any dot goes to specific screen. But I'm unable to see that in my screen. have no clue on why it is missing or any props that I'm missing. Please help me on this.

My code:

```
import React, { Component }  from "react";
// @ts-ignore
import Fullpage, { FullPageSections, FullpageSection } from '@ap.cx/react-fullpage';

export default class Home extends Component {

public render () {
    return (
    <Fullpage>
        <FullPageSections>
            <FullpageSection style={{
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                height: '100vh',
                padding: '10em',
            }}>1</FullpageSection>
            <FullpageSection style={{
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                padding: '10em',
            }}></FullpageSection>
            <FullpageSection style={{
                backgroundColor: 'firebrick',
                padding: '10em',
            }}>3</FullpageSection>
            <FullpageSection style={{
                backgroundColor: 'pink',
                padding: '10em',
            }}>4</FullpageSection>
            <FullpageSection style={{
                backgroundColor: 'coral',
                padding: '10em',
            }}>5</FullpageSection>
        </FullPageSections>
        <button onClick={() => window.scrollTo(0,0)} style={{
            position: 'fixed', 
            right:50, 
            bottom: 30
        }}>
        Top</button>
    </Fullpage>
    )
}}
```

Comment: i dont know about this npm , you can instead try css snap scroll for the same effects

Comment: Why not using the fullPage.js react wrapper? https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage

Comment: @Alvaro i tried  github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage , but it is a licensed one. i'm looking for an open source option.

Comment: @siri you can get a license for as little as 11 USD, not a huge price to deal with the official component :)

Answer (score 0):

Give some z-index value to the div enclosed Navbar. It will work.
If code in react:-

```
<div style={{zIndex:1000}}>
   <Navbar>
   ......
   ......
   </Navbar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing all the needed features for it. Kindly include FullpageNavigation so as to display the navigation dots needed.

```
 import React, { Component }  from "react";
    
    import Fullpage, {
      FullPageSections,
      FullpageSection,
      FullpageNavigation,
    } from "@ap.cx/react-fullpage";
    
    
    export default class Home extends Component {
    
    public render () {
    
     return (
   <Fullpage>
       <FullpageNavigation />
          <FullPageSections>
                <FullpageSection style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'green',
                    height: '100vh',
                    padding: '10em',
                    }}>1
                </FullpageSection>

                <FullpageSection style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                    height: '100vh',
                    padding: '10em',
                    }}>2
                </FullpageSection>
           </FullPageSections>
   </Fullpage>
    )
     }}
```